# In vanilla JavaScript, how to select elements created using innerHTML property after completely loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
      document.querySelector('#movies').innerHTML = `
        <div class="row">
          <div class="alert alert-primary w-50 mb-2" role="alert">
            New genre added.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card mb-2 w-50">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
```

From the code snippets, I am trying to select those elements with `.card-title` class

```js
  const cardsList = document.querySelectorAll('.card-title');
  console.log(cardsList);
```

but it keeps on returning an empty `NodeList`.

Is it really not possible to target those elements added using `innerHTML` property after the DOM has been created and the page already loaded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716713/how-to-target-elements-set-from-innerhtml-or-html-using-jquery

Comment: Please add a [mcve] preferable as [snippet (`<>`)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special treatment is needed. Nodes, once inserted, don't remember where they come from. Most likely, you're running query code before insertion actually happens.

```js
const name = 'Your Name Here';
document.querySelector('#movies').innerHTML = `
  <div class="row">
    <div class="alert alert-primary w-50 mb-2" role="alert">
      New genre added.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card mb-2 w-50">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

const cardsList = document.querySelectorAll('.card-title');
console.log(cardsList[0]);
```

```html
<section id="movies">Loading...</section>
```

Comment: This answer gave me the idea that I am updating the ```innerHTML``` from a promise and I've isolated it in a function while I am selecting those elements upon page load. That is the reason why the ```NodeList``` is always empty. My bad!